# Laravel: display multi data in one row for every user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

How I can display multi data in one row with foreign key by id user for example:
I have users with multi ticket, i need to display for every user number of his tickets in one column.

[image]

this my controller

```
public function followticket()
{
    $data = DB::table('tickets')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'tickets.user_id')
        ->select('users.*', 'tickets.*')->get();

    return view('Admin.suivi-tickest',compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: you can try with `groupBy` and raw select with `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: Look into using Laravel's relationships; you should be able to define one between `User` and `Ticket`, then query for `$data = User::with(["tickets"])->get();` (or something similar)

Comment: You can use DB::raw(<query>) and MySql functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with laravel model relationship

**User model**

```
public function tickets(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Ticket', 'user_id');
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function followticket()
{
    $users = User::withCount('tickets')->get();
    return view('Admin.suivi-tickest',compact('users'));
}
```

**OR**

If using query builder then you can try like this

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('tickets', 'users.id', '=', 'tickets.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', DB::raw('count(*) as tickets_count'))
            ->groupBy('id')
            ->get();
```

**Template**

```
@foreach($users as $user)
   {{$user->id}} {{$user->email}} {{$user->tickets_count}}
@endforeach
```